# Why are things like Gnome Terminal called "Terminal Emulators" instead of just "Terminals"?

Tags: terminal, terminology

What are they emulating that keeps them from just being terminals? What does a plain-old "terminal" look like, if they are just emulators?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> A terminal is the end of a line. So,
>   back in the day when the computer was
>   a mainframe serving many user
>   accounts, what you'd be sitting at
>   with your keyboard and display would
>   be a terminal.
>
> A terminal emulator is when you're
>   using a computer (a Turing machine) to
>   provide the function of a terminal in
>   software. This usage would typically
>   come up because the computer would be
>   'imitating' a particular type of
>   terminal in order to communicate with
>   the mainframe.
>
> A very popular terminal is/was the
>   [VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100). So if I telnet right now to the
>   server of the local [Freenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freenet) (if they
>   still exist) I'd be using VT100
>   emulation.

Source and more explanations are in *[Terminal or terminal emulator?](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-602991.html)*.

Comment: So when you're using a computer with no DE, just the command-line, would that still be an emulator, since it is just software?

Comment: Trumped again by Molly. I can't compete. ;o)

Comment: @Matthew pretty much so, yes.

Comment: @Matthew what is DE?

Comment: @Milan it's been 12 years, but from the context I think I meant "Desktop Environment".

Answer (score 9):

Until the 80's, there were no PCs, but mainframe **terminals**. These just had a command line interface with no GUI. The Linux terminal emulators we use today emulate the settings of those old terminals.

Answer (score 6):

Mainly for historical reasons. In the mid 1980s, when terminal emulators were invented, they were called "terminal emulators" to distinguish them from the "real thing." The term is ambiguous nowadays, because the "real thing" is obsolete and only found in very old installations or museums. See *[terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator)* and *[computer terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal)*.

This is a picture of a [DEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Equipment_Corporation) (Digital Equipment Corp.) [VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100), perhaps one of the most popular terminals of all time:

[image: VT100] (Credit: Flickr user [Jason Scott](https://www.flickr.com/people/54568729@N00))

Comment: Stop me if I'm wrong, but is the "real thing", when describing the terminal part of a computer, essentially just a typewriter that can be operated remotely? Hence the use of outdated terms like "linefeed" and "carriage return". And so, to simulate the act of interfacing with a OS in a human-readable/familiar format, software called "terminal-emulators" are used to handle and display text I/O. For example, `stty -a` will display row and column dimensions of the current terminal window depending on the font size, as if the terminal were a piece of paper fixed in size and loaded into a typewriter